# Create a button in Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I would like to create an action button in outlook. The problem is that this button should be distributable via GPO could anyone please guide me in a direction of how to do it in Outlook 2019 ?

Appreciate your help in advance,
Best regards,
Maks